# Drupal module to show data in table format

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

Is there a Drupal module which:

- opens a user-defined table in the same Drupal database
- displays all the columns and rows in HTML `<table>` format
- (best if) supports pagination
- (optionally) allow filtering of data range via SQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the table wizard and views modules combo.